# Is the following expression true or false? $\sum_{i,j=1}^n ij=2\sum_{1\le i< j\le n} ij+\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

$\sum_{i,j=1}^n ij=2\sum_{1\le i< j\le n} ij+\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$

where n is a positive integer.
I have just today learned the summation today and I still can't calculate this expression. I would be very thankful for your help.

Comment: it seems correct for me.

Comment: and can you maybe help me to calculate it?

Comment: I wrote a hint below, see it, if you need more details just say.

Comment: Thank you:) I try to solve it alone, but I'm not sure that I can do it.

Comment: to have an idea about it, try to have sum $ij$ when for example, i and j changes till 4. then you have $1.2+1.3+1.4+2.3+..\color{red}{2.1+3.1+4.1+3.2+..}+\color{green}{1.1+2.2+3.3+4.4}$

Comment: so, is the expression true?:)

Comment: yes, it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\{i,j\}_{1}^n= \{i<j\}_{1}^n\cup\{i>j\}
\cup \{i=j\}_{1}^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Start with the LHS. What happens to the terms when $i =j$? i.e. $ij = i^2$. Does $ij = ji$, e.g. $3 \times 4 = 4 \times 3$ ? If I allow only terms with $j >i$, am I missing half the entries?

Answer (score 1):

To compute the sum, write
$\displaystyle
\sum_{i,j=1}^n ij
=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n ij
=\sum_{i=1}^n i\sum_{j=1}^n j
=\sum_{i=1}^n i S
=S\sum_{i=1}^n i
=S^2
$

Now you need to know $S=\sum_{i=1}^n i$ , which is the sum of an arithmetic progression.